# WCF - notifications/writing in console application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

Is there any possibility to call method from WCF service like:

```
public void ShowNotification(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
};
```

I use this method in other one:

```
public void CreateUser(string name, string surname, string email)
{
    User newUser = new User();

    if (name != null && surname != null && email != null)
    {
        newUser.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        newUser.Name = name;
        newUser.Surname = surname;
        newUser.Email = email;
    }

    if (!UserExist(newUser))
    {
        SaveUser(newUser);
    }
    else
    {
        ShowNotification("User exist!");
    }
}
```

So when I make a call of CreateUser in my console application, I would like to get this message when user doesn't exist. How can I sent notifications to my console application?

For now it's just not working... Any ideas?

Comment: Make your method `public string CreateUser...` and return the desired string

Comment: Yeah, it's one idea... But then I should use it as Console.WriteLine(service.CreateUser(...)); and I don't want to do this. I want to use it just as service.CreateUser(...);

Comment: or `var result = service.CreateUser(...)`, and do whatever you want with the result

Comment: So there is no way to call Console.WriteLine() directly from WCF?

Comment: Your service is meant to run on a separate process in a IIS environment. your service doesn't even know that there is a Console

Comment: Well, indeed. Thanks for your advices :)